# Why can't I see both outputs from the two head functions in jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I use the below lines of code, the Jupyter Notebook only shows me the last head output called:

train_dataset.head()
test_dataset.head()

How can I see both of them without having to use a print function?

Comment: Try putting each one in a separate cell in the notebook.

Comment: You can run each on separate cells